# Adding a class to simple-form halm style

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, simple-form

I am trying to add the class "form-control" to a select tag like this am using rails, haml and simple form

```
= form.country_select "addr_country", class: 'form-control"
```

but I get this output:

```
<select id="order_addr_country" name="order[addr_country]">
<option value="form-control">class</option 
...
```

Any ide why?

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```
= form.country_select "model", "attribute", {class: 'form-control'}
```

don't know whether `addr_country` is a model or attribute

Comment: dosent work, I get this output now: <option value="input_html" class="form-control">input_html</option>

Comment: I missed that it was a `select` field. I haven't found a solution to applying styling to a `select` field.

Comment: just saw country_select gem and what you had was almost correct except you mixed single and double quotes in the class and you're missing a model or attribute - it requires 2 params, not including your `class` hash.